# How to count findstr results

Tags: cmd, findstr

I use 'findstr' to find certain common values in a lot of files and I get a list of all files containing it. Is there a way to count those results so I don't have to do it manually, or like enable row numbers in CMD?

Comment: Can you clarify that you just want the number of files which contain pattern matches. Or do you want the filenames, then the count? Or do you want each filenane preceded or succeded by an incrementing number? Your question is not clear, and until it is, we cannot answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically do something like:

```
c:\>findstr some-string file.txt > results.txt
```

This will pipe the command line output into a new text file named **results.txt**

Go to Windows Explorer.    Find results.txt file.
**Right-click** --> **Edit**
**Ctrl-A** to select all

**Look at very bottom of Notepad** to see the *total number of lines*.

Answer (score 0):

`I use 'findstr' to find certain common values in a lot of files and I get a list of all files containing it.`
So you probably use something like `findstr /m "searchstring" *.*`

`Is there a way to count those results so I don't have to do it manually`
yes, feed it through `find`, which can count:

```
findstr /m "searchstring" *.* | find /c /v ""
```

`or like enable row numbers in CMD?`
just for academic reasons (you already have your number):

```
findstr /m "searchstring" *.* | find /n /v ""
```

Just in case you need it as variable: use a `for /f` loop to catch the result:

```
for /f %a in ('findstr /m "searchstring" *.* ^| find /c /v ""') do set count=%a
```

(`%a` is command line syntax. Use `%%a` in a batch file)

Just in case Compo is right: to get the occurrences of the searchstring per file:

```
find /c "searchstring" *.* 2>nul
```

(`2>0` suppresses errormessages for folders (which `find` tries to search, but miserably fails because they are not files [well, technically they are, but that's out of scope for your problem]))